# Routes, path helpers and STI in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

This is driving me crazy! I have the two models `Lion` and `Cheetah`. Both inherit from `Wildcat`.

```
class Wildcat < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Lion < Wildcat; end
class Cheetah < Wildcat; end
```

STI is used here.

They all get handled through the controller `WildcatsController`. There, I have a `before_filer` to get the `type` of wildcat from the `params[:type]` and all the other stuff to use the correct class.

In my `routes.rb`, I created the following routes:

```
resources :lions, controller: 'wildcats', type: 'Lion'
resources :cheetahs, controller: 'wildcats', type: 'Cheetah'
```

If I now want to use the path helpers, that I get from the routes (`lions_path`,`lion_path`,`new_lion_path`, etc.), everything is working as expected, except the `show` and the `new` paths. For example `lions_path` returns the path `/lions`. The `new` path returns `/lions/new?type=Lion`. Same with the `show` path. When I try to enter `/lions/new` to my root domain it correctly adds the type param in the background.

So, my question is, why does Rails add the `type` parameter to the url if I use the path helper? And why only for `new` and `show`?

I am running Rails 4.0.0 with Ruby 2.0 using a fresh Rails app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why using `type`? Why not use inherited controllers?

```
resources :lions
resources :cheetahs
```

Then

```
class LionsController < WildCatsController
end

class CheetahController < WildCatsController
end

class WildCatsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_type

  def index
    @objs = @klass.scoped
  end

  def show
    @obj  = @klass.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @obj  = @klass.new
  end

  # blah blah

  def get_type
    resource = request.path.split('/')[0]
    @klass   = resource.singularize.capitalize.constantize
  end
```

Comment: Oh my god. It can be that easy. Thanks for that quick answer! I just didn't want to create controllers for each of the models as there will be heaps of them in the future. But that solved it!

Comment: My pleasure. That's the power of OOP :). Please note the templates will be wildcats'. If you want to use Lion's own say on index, just add a blank index method in LionsController. But I think a general view could do many job in most cases.

Comment: @Hiasinho, forget to add `singularize`. This solution has a little dependency on path but you should be able to get over it once path changed.

Comment: added it in my code before. But thanks for completing. It's funny how easy it can be sometimes. Always think simple. Lesson learned.

Comment: @bswinnerton it should be as simple as `resource = request.path.split('/')[1]` to return the second part of the split path instead of the first.

Answer (score -3):

I just had this problem. You could try to shutdown the server, remove the /tmp directory and restart.

[Rails routes and controller parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963437/rails-routes-and-controller-parameters)