# Rails routes and controller parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, polymorphism

I have those two resources which share the same controller. So far, my approach was routing with an special type parameter:

```
resources :bazs do
  resources :foos, controller: :foos, type: :Foo
  resources :bars, controller: :foos, type: :Bar
end
```

The routes work as expected, but all my links are like this:

```
/bazs/1/foos/new?type=Foo
/bazs/1/bars/new?type=Bar
```

instead of

```
/bazs/1/foos/new
/bazs/1/bars/new
```

How do I pass parameters to the controller without messing the links?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
resources :bazs do
  get ':type/new', to: 'foos#new'
end
```

For the verbs in which you need 2 IDs,

```
resources :bazs do
  get ':type/:id', to: 'foos#show', on: :member
end
```

Then you have both params[:bazs_id] and params[:id].

You can also do:

```
resources :bazs do
  member do
    get ':type/new', to: 'foos#new'
    get ':type/:id', to: 'foos#show'
  end
end
```

in order to always have params[:bazs_id].

For the root level conflicts you mentioned, you can do something like:

```
constraints(type: /foos|bars/) do
  get ':type/new', to: 'foos#new'
  get ':type/:id', to: 'foos#show'
end
```

Comment: I could do this, but then I would have to manually write every route. =o(

Comment: Plus, this could mess another routes I already have.

Comment: @rogi I guess you have to write other routes manually as it seems that you don't want to use :bars controller and :bars cannot be treated as a regular resource name. What are the other routes you already have?

Comment: Yes, but I also do have to make some root level routes like this. It's ok while prefixed with 'bazs/1/', but when you get '/:type/:id/*', teh problem starts

Comment: @rogi In that case, you can keep your routes in the OP only without the :type part, and parse request.fullpath in :foos controller to get the type part of it.

Comment: Wow teh constraints are cool!

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, `type:` is setting a parameter `type` which is appended on the URI.  Another option could be, for each route, to define `defaults`, which would be parameters only be accessible by the controller and not appear in the URI.

The [documentation on defaults](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) explains this pretty well.

Example:

```
resources :bazs do
  resources :foos, controller: :foos
  resources :bars, controller: :foos
end
```

Comment: This does not work as well.

Comment: Just got teh same result.

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: `/bazs/1/foos/new` and `/bazs/1/bars/new`

Comment: See my edit.  You don't need `type` or `defaults` at all.

Comment: Then, how do I get teh controller to know to which `type` I am referring?

Comment: Through the route itself:  `/bazs/1/foos/new` vs. `/bazs/1/bars/new`

Comment: Then, how do I parse teh route to find out which?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41130/discussion-between-cdub-and-rogi)